# Wordpress redirection problem after moving to a new server?

Tags: wordpress

I've created a site using wordpress and i moved that from localhost to new server.

The steps i've followed is just got backup of old db from localhost and uploaded them to the new server. Changed the WordPress address (URL) & Site address (URL) manually from phpmyadmin.

Moved all the files from localhost to the server

Changed the wp-config with the new server's db details.

Now i'm able to visit the admin panel of wordpress but not the site.

Its showing the following error,

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.
>
> ```
> *   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
> ```
>
> accept
>             cookies.

I think that this must some redirection problem..

My new .htaccess file under new server is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /veejata/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /veejata/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you use firefox, you can install the TamperData addon to see what kind of redirect loop the page gets into

Comment: @JohnP Couldn't find anything even after installing tamperdata.. The request are responded with 301 redirection...

Comment: you might have better luck on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It also helps if you supply a URL to the misbehaving site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the solution myself,

It was issue in the windows server with wordpress 3.1 
so i installed the Permalink fix pack @ [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/…](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/) .

Now its working fine..

I've no issues linux server.. I've to dive into the thing to know that is happening in windows server...

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset you permalink structure and then set your custom permalinks again ( via wp-admin ). It always work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution - caused by bad value set in REQUEST_URI - you can find it posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429363/wordpress-causing-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-error-remotely/28337107#28337107)