# Wordpress causing "This webpage has a redirect loop" error remotely

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a Wordpress site that works perfectly well in development (at `mysite.dev`), however when I deploy it to my remote server (`mysite.com`) it throws the '**This webpage has a redirect loop**' error.

I can see in the loading bar that the browser is trying www.mysite.com then mysite.com then www.mysite.com again and again, however I'm not sure if this is relavant or not.

If my Wordpress database configuration is incorrect, I get the **Error establishing a database connection** message, however when everything is set correctly it breaks in this re-direct loop thing.

I have changed the field in the database (`siteurl`) to reflect the remote settings (`http://mysite.com/wordpress`).

Note: My wordpress files are stored in a folder called `wordpress` in my root directory except for `wp-config.php`, `index.php` and `.htaccess`.

Any ideas?

.htaccess contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Comment: Well it is probably the .htaccess at fault. Please post its contents. You have a faulty domain rewrite in there.

Comment: This is the _only_ htaccess file? Is there one up at a higher level?

Comment: This is the one that sits in the root directory, and it seems to be the only one, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My hosted server settings were forcing mysite.com to www.mysite.com and this was causing the problem. I turned this setting off and everything works now, i'd still like to know how to make it work with this setting turned on, though!

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem (a redirection loop after migrating to a new server).

But it was **not a problem with the configuration values siteurl and home**, neither was it an issue with the .htaccess file. I tried all that. And it was also **not a problem about the 'www' added to the URL**.

After some researchs I found that the loop was caused by infinite calls to the redirect_canonical function (in wp-inclue/canonical.php).
But it was not a bug from wordpress. Some Php configs set the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in a "wrong way" when you acces your root url. Example : On my server, when I go to http://example.com/ the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is set to '/index.php' instead of just '/'
This is confusing for redirect_canonical because this function always try to redirect to the "better" url it knows for a page. And the better url for the root of your site is '/'. On my server, each time redirect_canonical tried to redirect to '/' it failed, and tried again until an infinite redirect loop was found.

To correct this bug, you can either modify your server configuration - I don't personnaly know how to do that, but I know it is possible - or if you can't change it, just add this code in a [custom plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) :

```
/**
 * avoid redirection loop in redirect_canonical if REQUEST_URI 
 * contains '/index.php' 
 **/

/* remove the action set in the hook 'template_redirect' by wordpress */
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

/* set a custom action in the hook 'template_redirect' to check REQUEST_URI value */
add_action('template_redirect', 'correct_redirect_canonical');

/* Function to correct the behaviour of redirect_canonical */
function correct_redirect_canonical(){
    if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/index.php')===false){
        redirect_canonical();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 4):

1.- As "My wordpress files are stored in a folder called wordpress" you must edit `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

**UPDATE**

2.- Try cleaning all cookies. This simple action (through Firebug) has solved this problem to me sometimes.

**UPDATE 3**

3.- Try this /index.php in your  root directory:

```
// index.php file in root directory
chdir('wordpress'); // change dir to WP
include 'index.php'; // execute WP with their normal `index.php`
```

and leave `/wordpress` directory as usual (with their normal index.php and .htaccess inside).

**I mean don't change any bit of the normal `index.php` of WP** that it is something like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: Wordpress handles all that for you unfortunately. However, I tried it just to be sure and the same error occurred.

Comment: @alex-coady Have you tried with distinct browsers. Also try cleaning all cookies.

Comment: I have tried clearing all Cookies yeah, the same error shows in all other Browsers (I tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari).

Comment: @alex-coady Answer updated. I think is the best solution to execute WP from the root dir. Good luck...

Comment: There isn't an `index.php` in the wordpress directory. That file is in my root directory. I think the problem actually lies with my remote server - thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @alex-coady that's why I suggest you leave `wordpress` dir as come out of the box, ie, don't move their `index.php` outside. Instead make another index.php in your root dir to automatically `change dir to WP dir` and include their `index.php` to execute it... check my UPDATE 3....

Comment: @alex-coady I tell you man. I have passed for this, try exactly that I suggest you in UPDATE 3 and you will be ready to party. By my side I already have my beer here... 8)

Comment: @alex-coady Please feedback. Did you resolved the issue. This issue is very common when you try to load WP outside of their directory. Please share! SO is not only to solve personal issues my friend...

Comment: @IgorParra i move my site from server to local and i update my .htaccess to thing that you say and the error that i get change from The page isn't redirecting properly to Internal Server Error. do you have any idea that i solve my problem? my question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860451/wordpress-move-site-from-server-to-localhost

Comment: @elham-gdz of course not, an Internal Server Error (500+) can mean lot of different things. You must to check the error log of your server.

Comment: @IgorParra i change my .htaccess settings and i have this error: The page isn't redirecting properly. can you help me to resolve it? when i set MULTISITE to false i can access to wp-admim but when i set it to true i can't access it, how can i fix it, i really need to access my site with it's network, can you help me? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the infinite redirection problem can also occur when using ***CloudFlare Flexible SSL***.  To fix it you need to install the following plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin like [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) which tracks URL changes?
This might have created a loop where it redirects mysite.dev/page/ to mysite.com/page/ and mysite.com to mysite.dev.
Happened to me before!

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen in one of two places, on the user side, or on the admin side.

When it happens on the admin side (wp-admin), you will find that you are unable to login.

Step 1: Connect to your blog using ftp and navigate to your wp-content/plugins/ directory and download all of your plugins to a folder on your desktop.
Step 3: Still in your FTP program, delete all plugin folders and php files in the plugins directory. You do not want anything at all left in this directory.
Step 4: Try logging into your blog. It should let you log in with no problems. Visit the plugins section of your blog. This should load with a lot of errors telling you that each plugin has been deactivated due to an error. This is ok.
Step 5: Using your ftp program you should upload all your plugins. Once uploaded you should activate each plugin one by one within wordpress and then visit the wp-admin/ login address to make sure that it will pass you through to your blog once logged in.
Step 6: When you activate a plugin and start getting this error again, you will know which one is to blame. Simply delete that plugin via ftp and start looking for an alternative plugin to use.

If these steps do not fix your problem, you should backup all your wordpress files and then delete them. You should them upload clean wordpress files for the latest version and try logging in with no themes or plugins uploaded. You can upload these later once you can login.

If you continue getting error, clear your browser cache, test logging in with other browsers.

If all else fails, contact your webhost or open a thread on the wordpress support forum

Answer (score 0):

I think that I may have an alternative/shortcut to this issue.

Instead of deleting every plugin and then reinstalling all of them one by one I suggest to start by deleting the lasted plugins because "resent problem = recent modification/plugins".

Answer (score 0):

Though I found this post and solution really helpful because this problem was driving me crazy and took me so much time to realize. In my case it happened because I moved the files inside the same server but using another domain and after finishing all configurations and replacements I was not able to view pages and got this error. 
 In my **hosting settings** there was a Preferred domain filed which was set to domain.ltd (I tried to change it but finally left it so) and than in **Settings->General** wordpress dashboard I had WordPress Address (URL) "mysite.com" and Site Address (URL) set to "www.mysite.com" after setting last value without www..bum everything is okay now. Hope this helps anyone else

Answer (score 0):

in my situation, locally - Openserver.

The problem appeared in capital letters in the address. For example, in the site settings it was `http://local-Host`, it was the capital letters that caused the problem, because the entire address is reduced to lowercase letters - `http://local-host`, and as result `$redirect_url` was different from `$requested_url` in canonical.php

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the answer was the `.htaccess` file and the redirects there.  It seems that the theme/plugins I was using wanted its own code which was similar to that on the wordpress site for `htaccess`.  I looked through the plugin and found the code it referenced and changed that in the `htaccess` file.  Now it works.