# Wordpress: Move Multisite from server to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to move a deployed WordPress Multi-Site to a local environment. I backed up the server database and files. In my local environment, I created a new database and imported the backup. I also copied the server files to my local machine.

I did these steps:

1. I changed **wp-config.php** and updated it with the new `db-name`, `db-username`, `db-password` and set `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysitename.com');` to `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/mysitename');`.
2. I changed `option_value` in the **wp-option** database table to point to my local address.
3. I also deleted these lines from **.htaccess**:

   ```
   # Redirect non-www urls to www
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysitename\.com
   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

But when I go to **127.0.0.1/mysitename** I get this error: *This webpage has a redirect loop*.

And when I change `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/mysitename');` to `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');` and I go to **127.0.0.1/mysitename** address it shows me the *phpinfo()* page.

How can I fix my problem?

Please explain if I must set something in **.htaccess** and **wp-config.php** files.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried completely deleting your local **.htaccess**?

Comment: @rnevius: yes, when i delete .htaccess, again shows the phpinfo() page if i set define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost'); and if i set it to define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/mysitename'); it will show this error: This webpage has a redirect loop .

Answer (score 26):

Edit: Recently had to migrate a multi-site once again, and this guide still works fine as of 01/03-2016. The database edits are very figgedy, one mistake and you either get white screen of death or error connecting to database, so pay attention :)

I couldn't figure out of to allow localhost links with protocol (http://) so if you see "(http:)localhost" read it as http:// localhost/. If someone could edit this for me that would be great!

## Normal Wordpress migration:

1. Backup your database from localhost.
2. Create new database on new server, import the exported database here.
3. Upload all Wordpress-files to the server.
4. Edit wp-config.php, changed database name, username and password. Usually below "define('WP_DEBUG'.. I define "WP_HOME" and "WP_SITEURL", these will override Wordpress database settings for path to root.
   "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE" is used for multisite installations. So if it isn't a multisite, don't use this, if it is a multisite, just use this and not WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL.

   ```
   define('WP_HOME', 'http://mysitename.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://mysitename.com');
   ```
5. If you uploaded .htaccess from localhost aswell, delete it from the server.
6. Visit http://mysitename.com/wp-admin, login and go to permalinks settings and press save to generate a new .htaccess.

And you're done! No need to bother doing database changes. For your localhost installation, just define WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to localhost instead.

## How to migrate multisite:

Multisites in Wordpress is a pain in the ass to migrate, it involves several database changes and even when you made everything correct it seems to only work some of the times without errors. However these are the recommended steps:

1. Export database, same as above.
2. Upload new database, same as above.
3. Add all your Wordpress files, same as above.
4. Edit your wp-config.php with the new database info, add the following defines:

   ```
   define('MULTISITE', true);
   define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); // true or false depending if the paths for each multisite is pointed by a subdomain.
   define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost'); // localhost is the DOMAIN of the new location, so even if the ABS_PATH is localhost/whatever, you should have localhost here.
   define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
   define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
   define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
   ```

You should have all of these in the wp-config.php of the site you are trying to export, so just copy-paste them from there, and edit DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE.

5. Edit your htaccess like this (Rewritebase /path/ should be relative path, ie if your website is located at localhost/mypage it should be "RewriteBase /mypage/"):

   ```
   # MultiSite
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /subfolder-from-localhost/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
   ```
6. Database edit time! These steps needs to be done for every subsite your multisite has, if I type change table "wp_site", you should replicate it in wp_site1/wp_site2 etc...

In table wp_options: change fields "site_url" and "home" to (http:)localhost/subfolder (no trailing slash).

In table wp_blogs: change "domain" to "localhost", and "path" for every entry for each subsite to /subfolder/ (must have trailing slash)

In table wp_site: change "domain" to "localhost", and "path" to /subfolder/ (must have trailing slash)

In table wp_sitemeta: change "siteurl" to full path ie (http:)localhost/subfolder/ (must have trailing slash)

7. Now you should atleast have access to your page, if you still get redirection loop or white screen of death, double check the database changes. Now login to admin, and we need to change some hardcoded URLs in the database, I usually do this with a plugin called "Seach and replace", so download and install this plugin, and use it by typing in what it should search for (old url) and what to replace it with (new url).

   ```
   Search for: http://mysitename.com
   Replace with: (http:)localhost
   ```
8. Now hopefully you have a functional migration of the multisite. As I noted I've done this a couple of times, and it almost seems random if everything works or not. I'd say I had success with this approach perhaps 6 out of 8 times.

Edit: Added how to migrate multisite.

Comment: Or just use [the Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/), and skip all of that. ;-)

Comment: @ninja: I also do these steps, i wrote that what steps i did.first thing that i don't know is i should set "DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE" to localhost/mysitename or localhost? and the second thing is that i have This webpage has a redirect loop error so i can't connect to wp-admin.

Comment: @ElhamGdz don't use DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE at all, just use WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL unless it is a multisite wordpress install. You should use these like "define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/dir');

Comment: @ninja my website is a multisite, as you explain in your answer if use multisite i should use DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE that  i used it.

Comment: You should edit your title/content to reflect it is indeed a multisite. I will update my answer how to migrate a multisite aswell.

Comment: @ninja i don't understand your answer.please explain more.

Comment: @ElhamGdz it's updated now. Takes a while you know ;)

Comment: @ninja...In order to use markdown to show code within lists, you need to indent by 8 spaces, rather than 4.

Comment: @ninja i exactly do these steps but i also get this error This webpage has a redirect loop and can't connect to wp-admin. in wp-config i have this: if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); and i set define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost/mysitename'); , is it true?

Comment: /** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
 define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

Not sure that line is necessary to edit for multisites tho. My guess is you missed something in the database edit, sounds like there's and old reference to another path, which then redirects it back creating the loop.

Comment: @ElhamGdz you could always try to migrate it and setting MULTISITE to false in wp-config.php, then when it is up and running (should be much easier), you could turn it into a multisite once again via wordpress admin tools.

Comment: @ninja i set false to Multisite and i can access to wp-admin but i need to access the other sites that run in this domain, how i turn multisite via wordpress admin tools?

Comment: @ElhamGdz http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network if you can access your mainsite after doing this, but not the subsites, you still need to change the database tables for each subsite.

Comment: @ninja i know that how create a network but my problem is that when go to tools--->create a network it is warning me that i have one network in database if you want to create a new one you should first delete this network from database and then create new one, but i need this network, how can i run this network?

Comment: @ninja do you have any idea?

Comment: If you are installing a multisite locally in XAMPP, besides what @ninja mentioned, adding virtual hosts as per this was required for me - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231143/65414  . Also make sure you add the required HOSTS entry as well

Answer (score 3):

This is close but a little different for a multisite that uses ***subdomains***. You are required to edit your host file to show each site url as localhost[(LINK)](https://wpdreamer.com/2013/08/how-to-setup-a-localhost-wordpress-sub-domain-multisite-environment/):

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost.com
127.0.0.1   subdom1.localhost.com
127.0.0.1   subdom2.localhost.com 
etc..
```

Then, editing the database as stated above worked, ignoring any subdirectory changes beyond the .htaccess mentioned above but leaving the Base as /

```
 # MultiSite

 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

In my install, I needed to update some  across the headers and footers to get the styles to load.

Thanks to @ninja for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Ninja's answer helped a lot. Though you can shorten the amount of the steps described in his answer by using wp-cli for database replacements, so you don't need any third party plugins and to edit single database cells manually. wp-cli's search-replace function works amazingly perfect, at least in my experience in case of usual wp sites. But in combination with the steps in ninja's answer it also has worked with multisite in my case. Here is a great description on how to install wp-cli: https://wp-cli.org

To replace a string through out all the sites run:

```
wp search-replace //oldurl.com //dev.url.test --network
```

Yes, the url strings are not wrapped with quotes. From my experience this way the replacement works perfect without any issues which might appear using quotes.

To replace strings in a particular site:

```
wp search-replace //oldurl.com //dev.url.test --url=https://oldurl.com
```

To see what urls are mapped to the sites:

```
wp site list --network
```

Though the db replacements worked well. I had to deactivate multisite in the wp-config.php (by removing all the multisite constant definitions) and all the plugins first and then to reactivate them from network dashboard.

wp-cli search-replace docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the tutorial at this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/).Its explained very nicely and is very easy to understand.

PS for step 6 i suggest you use Velvet Blues WordPress plugin